# Start a specific version of an application from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to launch mathcad from excel, which works fine except that it starts mathcad 15 and not prime 5.0. What do I need to change to get it to launch the correct version of the application?

```
Public Sub ExportToMathCad_test2()
Dim mc As Object
Dim wk As Object
Dim ws As Object
Dim path As String

Set mc = CreateObject("Mathcad.Application")
mc.Visible = True
path = "Z:\Dokumentstyring\Templates\MATHCAD\template.mcdx"

Set wk = mc.Worksheets
Set ws = wk.Open(path)
end sub
```

Comment: I think this is configured inside the registry : in your case an object "Mathcad.Application" seems to redirect to version 15. I'd advise you to check this in the registry (just search on that entry), and verify your computer for both versions (in fact, do you need both version of this application on your PC? Otherwise I'd advise you to uninstall the one you don't need).

Comment: I concur with Dominique's analysis - this issue also crops up with Office applications if more than one version is installed. The only really sure way, if more than one version must be installed, is to "shell" the application via the file path to the *.exe of the specific version.

Comment: "shell" the application via the file path to the *.exe of the specific version. Will this give me an object that I can work on?

Comment: @Dominique  I'd advise you to check this in the registry (just search on that entry) , Seems like its no clear text that is linked to that register, so I guess I will uninstall version 15.